# Syncing Multiple Macs using Time Capsule

Tags: macos, airport, migration-assistant, data-migration, sparsebundle

Can I use one backup (.sparsebundle) and sync to other Macs?
     Can I migrate my files scheduled from my primary Mac to secondary Mac using Migration Assistant or other tools?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this discussion on Apple's forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3558250) for additional information:  No, a backup facility is not intended to be used for syncing files, and as such, attempting to use backups in this manner will be troublesome, possibly corrupting system integrity.

Instead, use an application designed for this.  In addition to those mentioned in the referenced article, there are several available on the App Store found by searching "file sync".